# Sequence Pattern recognition with python

Tags: python, pandas, sequence

in an apparel company, there are **hundreds of stitching machines** that we need to monitor their performance(ex: how many pieces made,avg. time per piece etc ). For a particular day and for a particular machine, there is a **stitching pattern sequence**. So using that stitching pattern should be able to calculate the number of pieces.

sample of **given stitching pattern sequence** for a particular day and for a particular machine:

**2222**43**2**43

here 2=run, 4=fix, 3=cut.
even though this is a given sequence, **the actual scenario can be a little bit different.**
it can be **22222**4343**2**4343 (more run signals with fix and cut order change)
or **22222**4343**2**4343**2**4343 (with extra run signal, fixes and cuts at the end)

when looking at data, can identify this with the naked eye.

[image]

As I mentioned, looking at the data can identify these pieces separately. need to identify these pieces by a python code using the given sequence pattern.

Finally, need to identify the **number of pieces** for any given machine **using the given sequence stitching pattern.**

sample of another few given sequences(there a lot of sequence patterns):

**2**43**2**43,

**222**43**222**43**222**43

So, To do that need to build a common python code that can be able to change when the given sequence change.SO using that can be able to identify the number of pieces.

I built a code to count the pieces for a particularly given sequence, but I have no idea to **generalize this to identify any given sequence. Any suggestions and recommendations are highly appreciated!!!!**

My working:

just to count a **specifically given sequence**.(need to generalize this for any given sequence)

```
# Accumulate sequences of interest
seqs = []
seq_start = None

for index,row in df.iterrows():
    # Is the current row of interest? 
    of_interest = row.Signal == 2
    if of_interest :
        if seq_start is None :
            # First interesting row in a potential sequence
            seq_start = index
    else:
        # This row is no longer of interest, so see if a sequence has occurred...
        if seq_start is not None :
            # This row is not of interest. The sequence ended with the previous row.
            seq_end = index - 1
            # Enough rows to be a sequence?
            if seq_end - seq_start >= 3 :
                seqs.append([seq_start, seq_end])
        seq_start = None
```

In the above code, I identified as a piece if there are 3 or more run signals continoesly. seqs returns the number of pieces.